# Trying to create a To-Do list

Tags: javascript, html

```
<h1>TO-Do List</h1>
<input type="text" id="text1">
<input type="button" button name="btnAdd" value="+" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="addTask()"><br>
<ul id="addTask"></ul>
```

*javascript* *also getting the read only jslint error on "otpt"

```
function addTask() {
    var otpt = document.createElement('li');
    text = document.createTextNode(otpt);
    otpt.appendChild('text');


    document.getElementById("addTask").appendChild(otpt);


}
```

Comment: What lint error are you getting? Make sure you pass document as an extern. If lint is ECMA6, you should use const instead of var.

Comment: What is your question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what happens and when?

Comment: Error messages are not the unintended debris of a program crash, they are explicitly worded to provide information about what went wrong. You should always read them carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

1. `otpt.appendChild('text');` its a wrong declaration .
2. `document.createTextNode(otpt)` it will add the element not the typed text of input.
3. if you need to add with the input value to append `li` .call the input value to pass with `textNode`.see the below snippet

```js
function addTask() {
    var otpt = document.createElement('li');
    var val =document.getElementById('text1').value;
    var text = document.createTextNode(val);
    otpt.appendChild(text);


    document.getElementById("addTask").appendChild(otpt);


}
```

```html
<h1>TO-Do List</h1>
<input type="text" id="text1">
<input type="button" button name="btnAdd" value="+" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="addTask()"><br>
<ul id="addTask"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple like this:

```
document.getElementById("addTask").innerHTML += "<li>" + text + "</h2>";
```

Or if you will be use jQuery (also simple):

```
$("#addTask").append("<li>" + text + "</h2>");
```

Answer (score 0):

1) The problem line was :

```
document.createTextNode(otpt);
```

otpt is not text value, it is li element.
2) Also, you need to append child to `otpt` with `text` NOT `"text"`

3) Additionally you need to read the value from the input field.

You need to modify your code like this:

```js
function addTask() {
            var otpt = document.createElement('li');
            text = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('text1').value);
            otpt.appendChild(text);
            document.getElementById("addTask").appendChild(otpt);
  }
```

```html
    <h1>TO-Do List</h1>
    <input type="text" id="text1">
    <input type="button" button name="btnAdd" value="+" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="addTask()"><br>
    <ul id="addTask"></ul>
```